# Adding Language Bar and other Languages through Answer file possible?

Tags: windows-7, iso-image, unattended

I have to image laptops on a per semester basis and part of the imaging process requires me to make sure the language bar and some extra languages are installed to all users that might log in to these laptops.

I was wondering if there is a way to add extra input languages and the language bar to the answer file or if there is another way of doing this.  Can I add it later during the 'audit mode'?

OS: Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: What is the "answer file?"

Comment: An answer file is a file you can create for when you are syspreping windows for imaging.  It will make the whole out of box experience or (OOBE) very simple and seemless.  Usually the answer files are called unattended.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Inside the answer file, you need to use *lpksetup*

```
lpksetup.exe /i de-DE /r /p %SYSTEMDRIVE%\LangPacks
```

When Windows is already installed (e.g. the machine you have already rolled out), you can use *DISM* for this:

```
DISM /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\test\LangPacks\lp.cab
```

More information on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744278%28WS.10%29.aspx)

About the *Language bar*:

AFAIK is it automatically installed, and doesn't need to be installed separately. What could be is that is not automatically shown on your machines (although it appears automatically on my machine).

I think it could be this registry setting:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CTF\LangBar\ShowStatus

Try to set this value to "0", log off and login again. This should make it appear on the desktop.

Comment: And this will make sure it works for all users?  Does this just install language packs, or actually turn on the language bar?

Comment: Any language pack is always installed to the computer so all users can use it, Yes. For the language bar: According to this site, as soon as you have more than one language installed, the language bar will automatically appear: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-between-different-languages-by-using-the-language-bar-HA010362283.aspx

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know.  Thanks :)

Comment: That didn't seem to work.  The language bar wasn't installed by the unattend file.  Everything else worked though.

Comment: Okay, will update my answer.

Comment: I'll give that a shot but I just got done finishing 83 of my 105 machines to be imaged.  I have to get the other 22 done using defprof till Christmas.

Comment: Just wanted to add that before I imaged my next set I looked for this registry setting and it doesn't exist.